# Отправка сообщения всем клиентам (tcp, socket, async)

Tags: c#, асинхронность, сокет, tcp

Есть :
[сервер](http://cyber-blog.klan-hub.ru/2010/08/28/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF/"http://cyber-blog.klan-hub.ru/2010/08/28/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF/")
и
[клиент](http://cyber-blog.klan-hub.ru/2010/09/19/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF-%D0%BA/"%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA"). Когда сервер получает сообщение в ветку check_user:

```
private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {getalltables();
            log = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
            string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred);
            string[] tmp = str.Split('+');
            Console.WriteLine("{2} msg fr C№{0}({3}): {1}", ClientNumber, str, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(0,10), (Sock.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address);


            log.Write("\n");
            log.Write("{2} Client msg from Client №{0}({3}): {1}\n", ClientNumber, str, DateTime.Now, (Sock.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address);
            MemoryStream outtabl = new MemoryStream();

            switch (tmp[0].Trim())
            {
                case "check_user":
                    this.resp ="check_user"+"+"+checkUser(tmp[1].Trim().ToString());

                    SendAsync(this.resp);

                    Console.WriteLine("{2} msg to C№{0}({3}): {1}", ClientNumber, "success query " + resp, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(0, 10), (Sock.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address);
                    log.Write("{2} Message to Client №{0}({3}): {1}", ClientNumber, "success query check_user:", DateTime.Now, (Sock.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address);
```

как мне разослать строку "resp" все клиентам, которые в сети?(список из ClientConnection)
Если попытаться в

```
foreach(user in onlineusers)
{
user.sock.SendAsync(this.resp);
}
```

Выкидывает ошибку :

> An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько шагов:
1. Каждому клиенту необходимо иметь свою очередь отправки. Это можно реализовать, например, на ActionBlock'ах. Как только одна отправка завершилась, можно приступать к следующей. Если делать это параллельно, то можно нарваться на исключение (как у вас и получилось).
2. В таком случае вам будет эффективнее всего создать массов байт (то, что отправляем) и распихать в очередь всем клиентам. Они уже независимо друг от друга будут отсылать данные.

Кстати, SocketAsyncEventArgs не может работать параллельно с двумя сокетами.

Answer (score 0):

На шарпе уже давно не писал, но с неблокирующими сокетами штука такая, как только клиент начнёт читать из сокета, так на обработчик придёт соответствующее событие и в этот момент (в это самом обработчике) можно будет писать в сокет.

Все клиенты заблокируются на чтении последовательно вызовутся колбеки на сервере и вы сможете написать для каждого сообщение, вроде так последний раз  я делал в (java.noi).

Это очень популярная идея обработки нескольких соединений в одном потоке, потому думаю нет особенностей.